# How to create a hiding Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I create a menu navigation that will be hidden on load, but will show when the user hovers over a button?

So for better understanding I did a simple preview how I want:

[image: Layout mockup]

I know how to create a `<div>` with the menu the, only thing that I need to know is how to create the show/hide interaction with the mouse cursor.

What language do I need to use? Please tell me how can I create this. What should I search on the internet to create this? I'm not looking for complete code, just a small example or a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Search for css dropdown menu and you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: Get my ex boyfriend involved. He was very good at hiding food along with other things. Alternatively use the pseudo :hover in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with javascript.... Here is 2 links http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470771
Pretty sure you are looking for these events ;)

Comment: very nice this wasn't exactly what i was looking for but is kind of ^^ the good thing is that i will learn that so thank you.

Comment: Also in learning mode, good luck and dont forget to vote me up

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

Demo:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedBorderMenus/index5.html

Source:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/09/30/animated-border-menus/